# How do I implement FAQ on Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

I am struggling with the approach I should take to implement an FAQ using the Bot Framework. I considered using LUIS but found that I would have to create an Intent for every question. As there could be a large number of these (say 100), I wondered if there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to create an Intent for every question, that information design is not acceptable. What you need to do is to classify the types of questions you have and those classifications should be your Intents.

We're almost doing the same thing, so in my case I created an Intent called "Definition" for questions that usually starts with "What is..". I then try to train LUIS with all the possible questions asking for definition.

Since you're working on an FAQs, it is a finite set of information. You can basically use all FAQs and submit them as utterances and classify them in their proper Intents.

Comment: Yes that should drastically reduce the number of intents, thanks.

Comment: I'll just pile onto Romans answer as he's fundamentally correct. Just create a single intent like "FAQ" and then train a LUIS entity to extract the users question. From there use standard search techniques to find the most relevant definition. If you have a ton of FAQ's you can use a search engine like Lucene to search for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're doing is returning FAQ's it's not clear you need LUIS at all. Just use search techniques. You can use a search engine like Lucene or a simpler thing if you only have a few hundred FAQ's would be to write your own ranker that picks answers based on the number of words from the users query that match the document.

A fairly simple ranking algorithm would be to break the users utterance into tokens and then for each document search for each token within the document. Your score is generated by counting the number of tokens that matched within the document and calculating a coverage score. Coverage is basically what percentage of the terms in the users query match the document.

There are a couple of ways you can calculate coverage but here's a fairly simple approach. Add up all of the lengths of the tokens that matched and then divide that by the total length of the document/field being searched over.  So lets say we have the query "show me dogs from asia" and we have a document titled "Asian Dogs". We'd have 2 tokens in the users utterance that match, "dogs" and "asia". They have a total length of 8 and the title has a length of 10. So (8 / 10) would yield a coverage score of 0.8 for the title field.

You could do the same basic technique when searching over the document but you'd want to account for the number of times a term matched. Basically we want a document that has 5 occurrences of "dog" and 10 occurrences of "asia" to out rank a document with only 1 occurrence of each.

There are lot of other things you can add to your ranking algorithm like stemming & TF-IDF support but at that point you should just use a search engine.